# how to fix tensorboard errors that pop-up when I try to run it on terminal for a built graph

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I was trying to look at my Linear-Regression code graph using tensorboard but it gives out numerous errors that I can't find a workaround for. Also I'm running the code on my MacBook with intel m5 cpu and intel HD 5300 gpu.

The program works fine so I rechecked the code of any typo in the part where the graph is being created and stored. I even re-installed tensorflow (1.12.2) but the same error popped up. Also I can see the directory(where the graph is stored 'logdir') being created as soon as I run the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

lm = x * W + b

squared_delta = tf.square(lm - y)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(squared_delta)

optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)

train = optimize.minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    fw = tf.summary.FileWriter('./event_logs', sess.graph)

    for i in range(100):
        sess.run(train, {x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [0, -1, -2, -3]})
        #print(' cost : ', sess.run(cost, {x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [0, -1, -2, -3]}))

    print("Variables W and b: {} & {}".format(sess.run(W)[0], sess.run(b)[0]))

    test_data = 3
    print("Value for {} is {}".format(test_data, round((test_data * sess.run(W) + sess.run(b))[0])))
```

I expect to see a simple graph but...

```
Sarthaks-MacBook:PycharmProjects Xcalibre$ tensorboard --logdir="machine_learning/"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 34, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/Users/Xcalibre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
tensorboard --logdir="event_logs/"
```

That is where you are storing the files tensorboard should load. Have a look at this line in your code:

```
fw = tf.summary.FileWriter('./event_logs', sess.graph)
```

I guess that your project directory is named `machine_learning` and that is why you are trying to run:

```
tensorboard --logdir="machine_learning/"
```

But that's flat out wrong.